# Why do mathematicians take issue with treating dx as a number?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential

I'm learning about differentials on my own time. In the lecture the instructor mentioned that treating $dx$ as number was not a good idea. I'm not very clear why. Let's talk about it in concrete terms.

Say we have a square with the side $x$. The area of the square is $$A(x)=x^2$$ $$\frac{dA}{dx} = 2x$$ Here is what some might find controversial: $$dx*\frac{dA}{dx} = 2x *dx$$ $$\require{cancel}\cancel{dx}*\frac{dA}{\cancel{dx}} = 2x *dx$$  $$dA=2x*dx$$

From what I remember from my calculus class $dx$ and $dA$ are really small values, meaning I can multiply, divide etc. Can someone explain why what I am doing could be considered contoversial?

Comment: Please delete the word 'some' from your title.

Comment: It's difficult to say precisely what one means by "$dx$". If $dA$ and $dx$ are merely tiny (but finite) real numbers, then $dA = 2x dx$ is false. (We would only have $dA \approx 2x dx$.) If  someone claims that $dx$ is an "infinitely small number", it's unclear what that means because there are no infinitely small real numbers. Personally, in my mind I just think in terms of $\Delta x$ and $\Delta A$, tiny real numbers that satisfy $\Delta A \approx 2x \Delta x$. This "infinitesimal intuition" remains the key intuition behind calculus, and there's no need to throw it out.

Comment: What is $dx \times dA$? What is $dx+ dA$? $dx + dy$?

Comment: Let $(\rm{d}x)^2 = 0$. Hence, $$A (x + \rm{d}x) = (x + \rm{d}x)^2 = x^2 + 2 x \,\rm{d}x + \underbrace{(\rm{d}x)^2}_{=0} = A (x) + \underbrace{2 x \,\rm{d}x}_{= \rm{d}A}$$

Comment: @DavidK I never claimed such a thing.

Comment: In the context of differentials, it's fine until you "cancel" the $dx$.  This step is nonsense.  Rather, we would simply define $dA = \frac{dA}{dx} \cdot dx$.  No cancellation -- just the definition of the differential of a function.

Comment: Introduction to Calculus and Analysis I by Courant & John, page 172:

"The reason is that in many calculations and formal transformations we can deal with the symbols $dx$ and $dy$ as if they were ordinary numbers."

Note that, however, the concept of treating $dx$ and $dy$ as " infinitesimals "  is still rejected.

Comment: Note that dealing with the symbol $dx$ _as if it were_ a number is a formal manipulation, and is not the same thing as thinking that $dx$ _is_ a number.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Why not accept that $2+2=5$? We don't use $i$ just for kicks; it took some serious algebraic problems to get people to accept that it was a useful concept, and it has a rigorous definition. There is a rigorous theory of infinitesimals that accomplishes something like what you tried, but even that doesn't say that the square of an infinitesimal is actually _equal_ to zero.

Comment: @littleO Actually $dA=2xdx$ is exact. You seem to be confusing the differential $dA$ with the increment $\Delta A\approx 2x\Delta x=2xdx$. By definition, $df(x)=f'(x)dx$ is a function of the two independent variables $x$ and $dx=\Delta x$.

Comment: @bof I said that "**if $dA$ and $dx$ are merely finite but tiny real numbers**, then $dA = 2x dx$ is false." I'm pointing out the difficulty of defining $dx$. We can't simply say that $dx$ is a tiny number, and we can't say that $dx$ is an infinitely small real number. We would have to do something less obvious, such as defining $dA$ and $dx$ to be certain functions.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Indeed! That's where this kind of reasoning takes us. I prefer not to start down that path in the first place. Give me a good, well-motivated, sound mathematical theory in which $(dx)^2=0,$ then no problem.

Comment: @littleO How about this: Suppose $\frac{dA}{dx}=A'(x)$, then if we treat $dA$ and $dx$ as ordinary numbers, we can write an expression like $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta \gt 0$ such that $dx\lt \delta \implies dA=A'(x)dx+(error)\lt A'(x)\delta +(error)\lt \epsilon$.Note the error term approaches 0 much faster than $A'(x)dx$.

Comment: If I remember right, my calculus teacher (a famous mathematician) told us that $dy$ and $dx$ were any two numbers whose quotient was the derivative. That would have been around 1956. Maybe mathematics has gotten more rigorous since then. Or maybe my memory plays tricks on me.

Comment: From what I remember in my calculus class, the derivative is defined as $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$. I guess what I'm missing is wow do we come up with the notion of a differential from a derivative?

Comment: @BrianMoehring So what is a differential? How do I derive one?